# Autofac: registering hierarchy of classes

Tags: autofac, registration, hierarchy

I am struggling to register with Autofac a hierarchy of classes and interfaces.
I have an interface IMyService defined as below:

```
public interface IMyService
{
    void DoMyService();
}
```

And I have two abstract classes with implement this interface and called MyServiceA, and MyServiceB:

```
public abstract class MyServiceA : IMyService
{
      public abstract DoMyService();
}
public abstract class MyServiceB : IMyService
{
      public abstract DoMyService();
}
```

Moreover I have a second-level hierarchy for each of the two aforementioned services: MyServiceA1, MyServiceA2, MyServiceB1 and MyServiceB2:

```
public class MyServiceA1 : MyServiceA
{
    public MyServiceA1() : base() {}
    public void DoMyService()
    {
        // Implementation goes here
    }
}
public class MyServiceA2 : MyServiceA
{
    public MyServiceA2() : base() {}
    public void DoMyService()
    {
        // Implementation goes here
    }
}
public class MyServiceB1 : MyServiceB
{
    public MyServiceB1() : base() {}
    public void DoMyService()
    {
        // Implementation goes here
    }
}
public class MyServiceB2 : MyServiceB
{
    public MyServiceB2() : base() {}
    public void DoMyService()
    {
        // Implementation goes here
    }
}
```

I have in input two enums FirstEnum and SecondEnum used to select which of the four concrete types to instantiate:

```
public enum FirstEnum
{
      SvcA, 
      SvcB 
}
public enum SecondEnum
{
      Svc1, 
      Svc2
}
```

I want to register IMyService and by providing two enums, It will automatically instantiate the good concrete type.
For instance, if I want to resolve an IMyService and I provide FirstEnum.SvcB and SecondEnum.Svc2, it should instantiate the concrete type MyServiceB2 class. Moreover this hierarchy might be updated by adding some other concrete types etc, so I need a generic way of doing it

Does anyone have a clue to help me?

Thanks

Comment: If the thing resolving has to "know" about the internals and dependency chain, you're not doing dependency injection and should probably just new-up everything.

Comment: [Possibly related FAQ](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html) because usually questions like this are because the underlying issue is to ask how to pick a particular implementation by context or parameter.

Comment: [Also possibly related FAQ](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/injecting-global-parameters.html) because other similar questions want to pass the enum or other parameter to something in the middle of the resolve chain.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a specific service dynamically depending on a set of parameters, this is a good use case for an abstract factory:

```
public interface IMyServiceFactory
{
    IMyService Create(FirstEnum e1, SecondEnum e2);
}

public class MyServiceFactory : IMyServiceFactory
{
    private readonly ILifetimeScope scope;

    public MyServiceFactory(ILifetimeScope scope)
    {
        if (scope == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("scope");
        this.scope = scope;
    }

    public IMyService Create(FirstEnum e1, SecondEnum e2)
    {
        if (e1 == FirstEnum.SvcA)
        {
            if (e2 == SecondEnum.Svc1)
            {
                return scope.Resolve<MyServiceA1>();
            }
            else //svc2
            {
                return scope.Resolve<MyServiceA2>();
            }
        }
        else //B
        {
            if (e2 == SecondEnum.Svc1)
            {
                return scope.Resolve<MyServiceB1>();
            }
            else //svc2
            {
                return scope.Resolve<MyServiceB2>();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And now your consumer need to get the factory injected instead of the service:

```
public class MyServiceConsumer
{
    private readonly IMyServiceFactory factory;
    public MyServiceConsumer(IMyServiceFactory factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public void Do()
    {
        //var service = this.factory.Create
    }
}
```

Registration :

```
Autofac.ContainerBuilder builder = new Autofac.ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType<MyServiceA1>().AsSelf().AsImplementedInterfaces();
builder.RegisterType<MyServiceA2>().AsSelf().AsImplementedInterfaces();
builder.RegisterType<MyServiceB1>().AsSelf().AsImplementedInterfaces();
builder.RegisterType<MyServiceB2>().AsSelf().AsImplementedInterfaces();

builder.RegisterType<MyServiceFactory>().As<IMyServiceFactory>();
builder.RegisterType<MyServiceConsumer>();

//and quick test resolve
var container = builder.Build();
var test = container.Resolve<MyServiceConsumer>();
```